# When pushing to Vercel (production), the code is seen for 1 instant and then disappears + errrors

Tags: next.js13

This is my file structure:

```
- /app
  - /panel
    - page.js
    - layout.js
    - otherSubfolders ...
  - page.js
  - layout.js
  - globals.css
```

This is the content of my main layout.js:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return <>{children}</>;
}
```

This is the content of my main page.js:

```
export default function Login() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
}
```

When I enter in http://localhost:3000, of course I only see "Hello" and everything works perfectly, but when I push my code to my repository to deploy it to Vercel (production), I get no errors in Vercel logs but when I refresh my domain (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/), I see the content for 1 instant and then it dissapears.

If I go to the browser console, I get some javascript errors but I don't know how to treat them. It should work, I'm just adding a simple H1 in the root page.js of my Nextjs 13 project.

These are the errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Ed (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:23529)
    at rC (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:114352)
    at Jk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102245)
    at Mk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102217)
    at tk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102073)
    at qf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:97936)
    at MessagePort.P (2472-fd5e0bbca881c628.js:25:1665)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Ed (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:23529)
    at rC (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:114352)
    at Jk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102245)
    at Mk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102217)
    at tk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102073)
    at qf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:97936)
    at MessagePort.P (2472-fd5e0bbca881c628.js:25:1665)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Ed (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:23529)
    at rC (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:114352)
    at Jk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102245)
    at Mk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102217)
    at tk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102073)
    at qf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:97936)
    at MessagePort.P (2472-fd5e0bbca881c628.js:25:1665)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at rC (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:113541)
    at Jk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:102245)
    at Ik (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:101422)
    at df (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:101240)
    at ef (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:98669)
    at qf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:98092)
    at MessagePort.P (2472-fd5e0bbca881c628.js:25:1665)
```

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83850)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
    at pj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:83978)
```

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at vj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84869)
    at uj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84293)
    at vj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:85605)
    at uj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84293)
    at vj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:85382)
    at uj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84293)
    at vj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:85573)
    at uj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84293)
    at vj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:85382)
    at uj (https://preprod-audidat-clientes.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:84293)
```

```
Uncaught AggregateError
    at bf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:37338)
    at Ok (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:104450)
    at jf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:103338)
    at wk (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:98990)
    at qf (fd9d1056-3e7a21b32391def1.js:9:98476)
    at MessagePort.P (2472-fd5e0bbca881c628.js:25:1665)
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "audidat-clientes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "reactour": "^1.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3"
  }
}
```